# org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: END_TAG

Tags: java, android, web-services

My java server API use CXFClient test is ok:

```
result = CXFClient.getWebSeriveResult(wsUrl, "detailQuery", "{\"f\":\"4\",\"g\":\"1\",\"d\":\"20170301\",\"e\":\"0\",\"b\":\"510000RS\",\"c\":\"20100301\",\"a\":\"liaomalin\",\"h\":\"A1111\"}");
System.out.println(result);
```

And there is data in result, see the snapshot:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Also in SoapUI5.3.0 test is ok too:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

You see there is have resut data.

In android I invoke the API:

```
private void getDataForNet(int index) {

        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("a", "liaomalin");
        params.put("b", "510000RS");
        if (0 == type) {
            params.put("c", DateUtil.formatDate(new Date(), DateUtil.YEAR_MONTH_DATE));
          //  params.put("c", DateUtil.formatDate(new Date(), "20100301"));
        } else if (1 == type) {
           // params.put("c", DateUtil.formatDate(new Date(), DateUtil.YEAR_MONTH_NO_SYMBOL) + "01");
            params.put("c", DateUtil.formatDate(new Date(), "20100301"));

        }
        params.put("d", DateUtil.formatDate(new Date(), DateUtil.YEAR_MONTH_DATE));
        params.put("e", String.valueOf(workType));
        params.put("f", "4");
        params.put("g", String.valueOf(index));
        params.put("h", "A1111");
        String json = new Gson().toJson(params);
        Log.e("TAG", json);
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("agr0", json);
        WebServiceUtils.callWebService(this, "DataQueryService?wsdl", "detailQuery", map,
                getString(R.string.dialog_loading), false,
                new WebServiceUtils.WebServiceCallBack() {
                    @Override
                    public void callBack(String result) {
                        parseResult(result);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failed() {
                        DialogToastUtil.getDialogUtil().showToast(StatisticsListActivity.this,
                                getResources().getString(R.string.toast_net_check_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    }
                });
    }
```

It failed with the log data:

> 03-02 10:32:03.106 14877-14877/cn.cinsoft.smart3 D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 745K, 7% free 11769K/12580K, paused 1ms, total 2ms
>   03-02 10:32:03.122 14877-14877/cn.cinsoft.smart3 E/TAG: {"f":"4","g":"1","d":"20170302","e":"0","b":"510000RS","c":"20100301","a":"liaomalin","h":"A1111"}
>   03-02 10:32:03.146 14877-15110/cn.cinsoft.smart3 W/System.err: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: END_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body (position:END_TAG http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}soap:Fault>@1:266 in java.io.InputStreamReader@4abe7810) 
>   03-02 10:32:03.1** *****-*5110/cn.cinsoft.smart3 W/System.err:     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.require(KXmlParser.java:2056)
>   03-02 10:32:03.146 14877-15110/cn.cinsoft.smart3 W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:138)
>   03-02 10:32:03.146 14877-15110/cn.cinsoft.smart3 W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:63)
>   03-02 10:32:03.146 14877-15110/cn.cinsoft.smart3 W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:100)
>   03-02 10:32:03.146 14877-15110/cn.cinsoft.smart3 W/System.err:     at cn.cinsoft.smart3.utils.WebServiceUtils$2.run(WebServiceUtils.java:105)
>   03-02 10:32:03.146 14877-15110/cn.cinsoft.smart3 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
>   03-02 10:32:03.146 14877-15110/cn.cinsoft.smart3 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>   03-02 10:32:03.146 14877-15110/cn.cinsoft.smart3 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   03-02 10:32:03.146 14877-15110/cn.cinsoft.smart3 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   03-02 10:32:03.146 14877-15110/cn.cinsoft.smart3 W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
>   03-02 10:32:03.174 14877-14877/cn.cinsoft.smart3 W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
>   03-02 10:32:03.186 14877-14877/cn.cinsoft.smart3 W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
>   03-02 10:32:03.194 14877-14877/cn.cinsoft.smart3 D/callWebService: failednull

---

I don't know if somewhere did not config right. other API write in java use this method invoke is alright, but this one is fail.

Why use android monitor invoke this API fail?

Answer (score 1):

There maybe caused by ksoap version .

You try to update to a newer version.

If your kSoap version is under 2.4, you should upgrade to 2.5.8 at least.